# jQuery fadeout on scroll - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, fadeout

I am trying to implement http://jsfiddle.net/NKgG9/6/ into my website.

It's supposed to fade out a div when the user starts scrolling down. Instead the div just sits there, comlpetely visible and unchanging. I'm a massive newbie to java so figure it's something really basic and fundamental I'm missing.

Here's what I'm doing:

Inside the head tag:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var targets = $(".scroll_note, .social");
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 10){
      targets.hide();
    }
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(pos > 10){
            targets.stop(true, true).fadeOut("fast" );
        } else {
            targets.stop(true, true).fadeIn("fast");
        }
    });
});?
</script>
```

And then inside the body tag:

```
<div class="scroll_note">Scroll down to see our amazing specials!</div>
```

Please help me!
Thanks, Alex :)

Comment: Can you post more of the source code from your actual website? Additionally, are you loading your page from `file:///` or `http://` (i.e. from a local file or from a webserver)?

Comment: Your jsfiddle works fine for me.

Comment: @Wyatt http://www.happytobevisuals.com/index2.php

Comment: @TNC Yeah, I know, that's why I'm sure it's my fault (I didn't create the jsfiddle). All I've done is copy that jsfiddle's java code, put it inside script tags inside the head of my page, after calling jquery.min.js, and put a related div on the page. Is there something else I should be doing that's not shown on the jsfiddle screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other script you include, `fadeslideshow.js`, calls [`jQuery.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) which removes the global assignment of jQuery to the `$` variable. You have a few ways around this:

1. Remove the call to `jQuery.noConflict` in `fadeslideshow.js`. This may break that slideshow script, however.
2. Use `jQuery` instead of `$` in your JavaScript code above.
3. Wrap your code in a [self-invoking function](http://2007-2010.lovemikeg.com/2008/08/17/a-week-in-javascript-patterns-self-invocation/) that remaps the global `jQuery` to `$`:

   ```
   (function($) { /* your code here */ })(jQuery);
   ```

Comment: I think options 3 has the least side effects.

Comment: Yeah, I'd go with option 3. It's generally a good idea to do that *anyways*, too, as you lower the risk of leaking global variables (like `fadeslideshow.js` has done).

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, it's working.I took out the jQuery.noConflict in fadeslideshow.js.

Comment: Also, @Tyrsius, you were right about the ? - it doesn't work with it in there. I've also implemented the })(jQuery); thank you Wyatt Anderson. Much appreciation to both of you!

Comment: @AlexKarasulas you should accept Wyatt's answer, in that case (and consider upvoting mine, if it helped)

Comment: Oh, cheers! I've accepted Wyatt's answer, I'm too new to upvote yours though, even though I'd like to...

Answer (score 1):

You have a `?` at the end of your code that is going to throw an error and kill the script. Remove it and you should be all set.

**Edit:**

I see you posted your site. Your `script` tag pointing to the google API is malformed. It doesn't start with `http:`, just starts with `//`. Fix that, then see where you are

**Edit2**: Wyatt pointed out this is not true. See his answer.

Comment: I did it, and nothing changed :(

Comment: That's not the issue; that convention allows the script tag to be loaded automatically with `http` or `https` depending on the page environment. It'll break if you load it via `file://`, though.